# How to rotate number at index[1] in a nested list python

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am working on a problem that need me rotate the numbers at index[1] in a nested loop once toward the right. The nested loop looks like this `[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (1, 5)]` and i want the nested loop to look like this
`[(1, 5), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (1, 4)]` (All the number at index[1] moved once to the right) I want to do this at a range of N times. I tried using deque from the module collections but it didn't do the thing i wanted. Here are my code.

```
from collections import deque
n = int(input())
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
s, f = map(int, input().split())
num = 0

sequence = [i for i in range(1, len(a) + 1)]
res = list(zip(a, sequence))
print(res)
for i in res:
    res1 = deque(i[1])
    res1.rotate(1)
    print(res1)
```

I got an error on line 11

```
   res1 = deque(i[1])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Show your and clarify your question

Comment: What's that about N times?

Comment: @superbrain i want to rotate the numbers at index[1] n times. But n could be any number

Answer (score 4):

Could separate them into firsts and seconds, shift the seconds, and recombine:

```
a, b = zip(*lst)
lst = [*zip(a, b[-1:] + b[:-1])]
```

or just

```
a, b = zip(*lst)
lst = [*zip(a, b[-1:] + b)]
```

Use `-n` to rotate n steps (if `n` can be negative or longer than the list, take it modulo the length of the list first).

Comment: `list(zip(a, b[-1:] + b[:-1]))` will do as the 2nd line, I think it's slightly more readable to use `list(iterable)` than it is to use `[*iterable]` as the syntax may confuse some devs that aren't used to it

Comment: @IainShelvington I used to think so, but I got used to `[*iterable]`. Maybe people will get more used to it over time (except those people who still write `set([4, 2])` instead of `{4, 2}`).

Answer (score 2):

It could be a one-liner:

```
[(x[0], y[1]) for x, y in zip(l, l[-1:] + l)]
```

but Superb rain's answer is more explicit/pythonic

Comment: Ha, I actually prefer yours. I think I just thought `zip` as soon as I saw those tuples, never even considering a list comp here.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of it - Optimized solution:

```
from collections import deque
def rotate_second_indices(lst, n=1):
    assert n < len(lst)
    buffer = deque(lst[i][1] for i in range(-n,0))
    for index, (a, b) in enumerate(lst):
        lst[index] = (a, buffer.popleft())
        buffer.append(b)
```

---

Original answer

That code should do it:

```
lst = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (1, 5)]
new = lst[-1][1]
for index, (first, second) in enumerate(lst):
    lst[index] = (first, new)
    new = second
```

Another option:

```
lst = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (1, 5)]
first_lst, second_lst = zip(*lst)
second_lst = list(second_lst)
second_lst.insert(0, second_lst.pop())
lst = list(zip(first_lst, second_lst))
```

And another option:

```
first, second = zip(*lst)
second = deque(second)
second.rotate()
lst = list(zip(first, second))
```

Comment: You mean *was* it wrong? I think it was downvoted when you only had the first solution. And I think that one doesn't scale well to the desired larger rotations, maybe someone didn't like that. But I love the deque one, so have my upvote :-)

Comment: @superbrain Thank you :-) I do think a buffer of rotations together with the first solution is more scalable tbh. I've upvoted your answer, but like my 2 other solutions, it causes copying of the data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with buffer of rotations. But presumably it requires a bigger code rewrite than passing `n` to `rotate` :-)

Comment: Oh and I guess we could do the n-rotation in-place with O(1) extra space with the old triple-reverse trick.

Comment: @superbrain Triple-reverse? I've posted the memory-optimized solution. If you're not creating a new list, you must hold at least `O(k)` space where k is the rotation count.

Comment: Meh, that "highly memory-optimized" version takes O(n) extra space. I meant [this](https://repl.it/repls/DeliriousLightgreenCores#main.py), which only takes O(1) extra space.

Comment: @superbrain that's actually quite brilliant, never thought of this. Why does this work... Does require 3 passes over the data though.

Comment: Only *two* passes, really. The two partial passes together make one complete pass. But yes, it's probably slower. Only *memory*-optimized.

Comment: @superbrain True. I'd still prefer the solution I posted above. It all depends on the data ofc, but I presume a large sequence with small rotation count is the general case. It can further be optimized if the rotation occurs backwards, in which case it can even be applied on an infinite stream of data.

Comment: But then again making 2 passes over the data is still O(n)(time) and is equivalent to 2 operations each pass so meh.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate-by-n with O(1) extra space<sup>[*]</sup> using the old triple-reverse:

```
a = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (1, 5)]
n = 2

def reverse(start, stop):
    i, j = start, stop - 1
    while i < j:
        a[i], a[j] = (a[i][0], a[j][1]), (a[j][0], a[i][1])
        i += 1
        j -= 1
k = -n % len(a)
reverse(0, k)
reverse(k, len(a))
reverse(0, len(a))

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 1), (4, 2), (1, 3)]
```

<sup>[*]</sup>: Except when there are other references to the tuples, in which case they can't go to the [free list](https://rushter.com/blog/python-lists-and-tuples/) and become reused.

Answer (score 0):

You had a good start with `collections.deque`:

```
from collections import deque

f = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (1, 5)]

d = deque(map(lambda x, y: y, *zip(*f)))

d.rotate(1)

list(zip(map(lambda x, y: x, *zip(*f)), d))
```

```
[(1, 5), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (1, 4)]
```